# C# project building with csc in console - getting two errors on all classes

Tags: c#, csc

I'm trying to compile a whole C# project with csc in the console. The goal is to create a dll file and I used **csc -target:library -out:xyz *.cs**.

My project directory looks like this: the classes I wrote for the project, and then there's a \lib sub-directory in my project directory with other classes I referenced in my code.

Sadly, I'm getting tons of those errors:

- **error CS0246**: The type or namespace name 'xyz' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
- **error CS0115**: 'xyz': no suitable method found to override

for pretty much every class.

It's almost like the compiler ignores everything in the subdirectory. How do I include the library classes inside \lib with csc? Do I somehow need to tell csc the structure of the subdirectory?

Already googled a lot and really don't know what to do...
I'd be very glad if someone could help me out here.

Comment: Share some of the code. Otherwise it's pretty impossible to tell

Answer (score 3):

Running `csc *.cs` compiles all files in the current directory. If you want to also compile everything in a subdirectory, you can either manually specify the subdirectory, or you can use the `-recurse` option ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/recurse-compiler-option)). For example:

`csc -target:library -out:xyz -recurse:*.cs`

This will compile all `.cs` files in the current directory. You can even specify a specific directory to recursively compile, if that is what you want:

`csc -target:library -out:xyz -recurse:subdirectory/*.cs`

This will compile all `.cs` files in the 'subdirectory' directory, and all directories below it.